# How to check if screen is touched for more than 2 seconds

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

Which is the best and more optimized strategy to check if the screen has been touched for 2 seconds or more without stopping the main UI thread?

I have checked some sample codes but I'm not sure which is the best approach to achieve it, and also I need to do it without stopping the main UI thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can implement an `OnTouchListener` like this:

```
public abstract class TouchTimer implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private long touchStart = 0l;
    private long touchEnd = 0l;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.touchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.touchEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long touchTime = this.touchEnd - this.touchStart;
                onTouchEnded(touchTime);
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onTouchEnded(long touchTimeInMillis);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new TouchTimer() {
    @Override
    protected void onTouchEnded(long touchTimeInMillis) {
        // touchTimeInMillis contains the time the touch lasted in milliseconds
    }
});
```

The method `onTouchEnded()` is called once the touch ends.

Comment: Hi, your code seems nice but, what should i do with that onTouch(long timeInMillis) method? The abstract method onTouch in type MainActivity can only be defined by an abstract class

Comment: I show how to use the `OnTouchListener` at the bottom of my answer. You implement the `onTouch` method when you create a new `TouchTimer` instance.

Comment: thanks, but, how can i know when all the fingers have been done ACTION_UP ?

Comment: What do you mean? I just tested it to be sure, but if you consume the touch events properly - like my `TouchTimer` does - then multi finger touch events are treated as one big touch event. I used exactly the `TouchTimer` above and it measures the time between the first touch until the last finger is lifted. I can even change fingers during the measurement as long as I don't loose contact to the display it will all be treated as one big touch event.

Comment: in my phone it works like you tell, but if i try it on a tablet, it not works because ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP are being called a lot of times if i put the whole hand in the screen

Comment: Yeah hat happens sometimes. This particular device just doesn't handle the touch events correctly. You could implement a check for this if it is really necessary but unless this is some major device which a lot of the users of your app are going to use I wouldn't bother. You can never be certain that OEMs implement something correctly and sometimes they just mess up like this. But that has nothing to do with you, the manufacturer messed up and it is his responsibility to fix the devices.

Answer (score 1):

I used a `OnTouchListener` on a `RelativeLayout`. I hope this will help you.

```
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration >= MIN_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TOUCHED FOR" + clickDuration + "MS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                longClickActive = false;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (longClickActive == false) {
                    longClickActive = true;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "touch!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (longClickActive == true) {

                    longClickActive = false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution is actually not that good. You always return true, which might actually work in this case, but it is still not that smart. You only want to consume those touch events which actually interest you, so you should return true only when the `MotionEvent` is `ACTION_UP`, `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_MOVE`. In any other case you should return false. See my answer for more information. Also your example seems overly complicated for this simple use-case.

Comment: simply it is ontouch listner. am not finding it complecated. it is working fine i tested

Comment: Yeah it works fine, but your example has a lot of unnecessary checks and logic which are not required. For example the check for `MIN_CLICK_DURATION` or `longClickActive`. I can understand that one might implement such features, but it is not what @AndroidUser99 asked for. Anyway @AndroidUser99 will decide which of our answers he likes best.

Answer (score 0):

All gesture detection parts of Android code internally use combination of Handler class and postDelayed method. You can use it to post pieces of code to be run after arbitrary amount of time (for example 2 seconds).

1. override dispatchTouchEvent
2. if event is a press event, get Handle, postDelayed runnable and save it
3. if event is a release/cancel event, remove all your previous runnables
4. wait 2 secs for code to be run

   ```
   Runnable runnable;

   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           runnable = new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   //do something
               }
           };
           getHandler().postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
       } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
               || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
           getHandler().removeCallbacks(runnable);
       }
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
   }
   ```

see: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable), long)